# Possible to select between different Boost pseudo-random number generators at run-time?

Tags: c++, boost, random

I'm using the Boost Random library to generate random numbers for a Monte Carlo simulation. In order to check my results, I'd like to be able to use different RNG engines for different runs. Ideally I'd like to use a command-line option to determine which RNG to use at run-time, instead of e.g. selecting the RNG at compile-time through a typedef.

Is there a base class T such that something like the following is possible; or if not, an obvious reason why not?

```
#include <boost/random.hpp>

int main()
{
    unsigned char rng_choice = 0;
    T* rng_ptr; // base_class pointer can point to any RNG from boost::random

    switch(rng_choice)
    {
        case 0:
            rng_ptr = new boost::random::mt19937;
            break;
        case 1:
            rng_ptr = new boost::random::lagged_fibonacci607; 
            break;          
    }

    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dice_roll(1,6);

    // Generate a variate from dice_roll using the engine defined by rng_ptr:
    dice_roll(*rng_ptr);

    delete rng_ptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html) for type erasure.

*Edit:*
A simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/random/uniform_int_distribution.hpp>
#include <boost/random/mersenne_twister.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::random::mt19937 gen;
  boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 6);

  boost::function<int()> f;

  f=boost::bind(dist,gen);
  std::cout << f() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/random/mersenne_twister_engine.html) for mersenne twister for instance it seems there is no base class. It seems you will have to implement the class hierarchy you need.

Comment: Why would you look at the source? If there is no documented base-class, you should not assume there is one.

Comment: A statement like the one I make "There is no base class" should always be supported in some way. I might have missed it in the documentation or may be just guessing. The source code is a rock solid evidence. In general to provide a way to verify your statement is not a bad practice in my opinion.